# Using exec() php for a c# program

Tags: c#, php

I would like to create give some elements to my C# programm with exec function in PHP.

Here is my PHP :

```
$r = $_POST['r'];
$g = $_POST['g'];
$b = $_POST['b'];

$a = array($r,$g,$b);
exec( 'DMX\DMXController.exe',$a);
```

I just want to send a simple array

Here is my C# :

```
private static int r, g, b;
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        r = Convert.ToInt32(args[0]);
        g = Convert.ToInt32(args[1]);
        b = Convert.ToInt32(args[2]);
        start();
    }
```

I don't even see my programm's console launch when I execute exec() command with PHP.

Thank you for your help

Comment: The second arg doesn't pass the array like args. It just saves the result. Try with `exec("DMX\DMXController.exe $r $g $b");`

Comment: You are my saviour !
Thank you a lot :)

Comment: If $_POST data is user-supplied to be passed, read about [escapeshellarg()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) and [escapeshellcmd()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php) just for security!

Comment: I'll see that,
Thank you